# SQL Server SPID doesnt change for every connection

Tags: sql-server, pid

We are building an ERP system, and sometimes we need to see the SQL statement in SQL Server Profiler for debuging purposes. I can catch my ERP's queries by the SPID on Profiler. My ERP doesnt keep an open connection, it opens a connection everytime it needs it.

I have been thinking that everytime my ERP opens a connection, it should get a new SPID. How does it give the same SPID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPIDs are recycled, they are guaranteed to be unique at any one time, but if a connection drops, its SPID can be reused by a new connection.